# Photoshop Layer for Demonstrating Gestures on iOS

Tags: mobile, ios, iphone, gestures

I'm building demonstration screenshots of how to use an app and would love to be able to show tap, drag, pinch, and zoom events.

This video shows some really good ones:

http://vimeo.com/19347629

[image]

Are there any resources (PSD templates, etc.) that I could use to demonstrate in still screenshots these taps and gesture events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for: http://www.mobiletuxedo.com/touch-gesture-icons/

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of different resources from different contributors for representing gestures. Personally I like the style of the gesture set which designed for Ice Cream Sandwich:

[image]

Link to download:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aczgz2wkawolqlb/gestures.ai